# Incomplete python source distrubtion when building Fortran/Numpy extension

Tags: numpy, python-packaging

When building a source distribution of a Python package that contains a Fortran/Numpy Extension, the source distribution is incomplete. It lacks the source files `fortranobject.c` and `fortranobject.h`, which are copied by numpy's own `setup` function when you do a *binary* build (`bdist`), or a local install. However, if you do a *source* build (`sdist`), these files are not packaged. As a result, the source distribution cannot be used to locally build a binary wheel, hence a local install also fails.

Originally, I reported this as a bug in `pypa/build` (see: https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/326). However, I think the problem is with `numpy`, and not with `pypa/build`, because the same problem arises when you do a traditional `python setup.py build_ext sdist` to build a source distribution.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally tracked down the issue, which I think is a bug in how `Extension` in Numpy's `distutils` handles `pyf` source files. Here's the bug report: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19441.